# Snap Point to Specific Edge of Polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, point, arctoolbox, parcel

I am working on parcel and point data. I converted polygon (parcel) to point features using ARctool box i.e. feature to point (Original labelled in picture). After this step I want to bring all point on edge of each polygon (Final Result picture). I tried to use snap tools (from Arctool box ), it gives output on nearest edge (shown in picture After Snap) but I need all points on front edge (Final Result Picture).

If there is any existing tool or script (python or VB) which can give me desired output?

[image: Sample Data of Final Output]

Comment: Probably you should snap points to lines that can be made from polygons. Try to convert polygons to lines then make a dissolve layer from polygons and get lines that are on the edge of dissolved polygon (Intersect). Finally snap points to these intersections layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The would be a four step process, involving determining which polygons don't have overlapping sides.

Given:

[image]

1. Initiate a feature to line on your parcel feature class.

[image]

2. Perform a spatial join on the line feature class created in step one. Match option is `SHARE_A_LINE_SEGMENT_WITH`.

[image]

3. Perform a `Select By Attribute`on the spatial join feature class using the SQL where clause `Join_Count = 1`.

[image]

4. Perform your snap on the spatial join feature class with the above selection applied.

[image]

Voila:

[image]

Quick and dirty script:

```
lineFc = r"C:/Users/e1b8/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/Test_FeatureToLine"
arcpy.FeatureToLine_management("Test", lineFc)
sjLineFc = r"C:/Users/e1b8/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/Test_FeatureToLine_SpatialJoin"
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(lineFc, lineFc, sjLineFc, match_option = "SHARE_A_LINE_SEGMENT_WITH")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (sjLineFc, "Test_FeatureToLine_SpatialJoin", "Join_Count = 1")
arcpy.Snap_edit("Test_FeatureToPoint", "Test_FeatureToLine_SpatialJoin EDGE '500 Feet'")
```

Comment: Thanks Brundage this method really reduced my effort up to 90%. Thanks you so much.